# xmppStreamDidConnect not getting called in "swift framework"

Tags: swift, xmppframework, swift-framework

I'm creating the **framework in swift**, using **cocoapods** I have added **XMPP framework**  but somehow **can't able to connect to my host** :

my set up:

```
class XMPPController: NSObject ,XMPPStreamDelegate{

 var XMPP_HOST = "**************";
 var userJid:XMPPJID = XMPPJID();
 var password = "";

var xmppStream:XMPPStream;

init(jid: String, password: String) {


if let userjabberid = XMPPJID(string: jid) {
    self.userJid = userjabberid;
}
self.password = password;

self.xmppStream = XMPPStream();
self.xmppStream.hostName = XMPP_HOST;
self.xmppStream.hostPort = 5222;
self.xmppStream.startTLSPolicy = XMPPStreamStartTLSPolicy.allowed;
self.xmppStream.myJID = self.userJid;

super.init();
self.xmppStream.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
}
```

and my connect method:

```
func connect() {
if !self.xmppStream.isDisconnected {
    return
}

do {
    try self.xmppStream.connect(withTimeout: XMPPStreamTimeoutNone);
} catch let err {
    print(err);
}

}
```

and my delegate methods:

```
func xmppStreamWillConnect(_ sender: XMPPStream) {
    print("will connect");
}
func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, socketDidConnect socket: GCDAsyncSocket) {
    print("socket")
}
func xmppStreamDidStartNegotiation(_ sender: XMPPStream) {
    print("negotiate")
}
func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceiveError error: DDXMLElement) {
    print(error);
}
func xmppStreamDidDisconnect(_ sender: XMPPStream, withError error: Error?) {
    print("disconnected");
}
func xmppStreamDidConnect(_ sender: XMPPStream) {
    print("connected");
    try! sender.authenticate(withPassword: self.password);
}
func xmppStreamDidAuthenticate(_ sender: XMPPStream) {
    print("authenticated");
}
func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didNotAuthenticate error: DDXMLElement) {
    print("Stream: Fail to Authenticate");
}
```

here, only `xmppStreamWillConnect` gets called and all other delegates methods are not called.

Comment: Where you are calling connect function?

Comment: I'm calling it in public class of my SDK

Comment: @Budhabhooshanpatil, I am facing the same issue. Have you found any solution? I even made the singleton of XMPPController, but didn't help me. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to init `XMPPController` like below and call connect function:

```
self.xmppController = XMPPController(jid: String, password: String)
self.xmppController.xmppStream.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
self.xmppController.connect()
```

Comment: of course, I'm doing it, that's why the  "xmppStreamWillConnect" is working, the main concern is all other delegate methods are not getting called.

Comment: In your question it is mentioned xmppStreamDidConnect not getting called in “swift framework”

Comment: Yes , Difference is-->  i -  **xmppStreamDidConnect** not getting called , ii - **xmppStreamWillConnect** is getting called

Answer (score 0):

solved by making singleton of my class as fallows:

```
static let sharedInstance = XMPPController();
```

And calling it as :

```
XMPPController.sharedInstance.connect(Withjid: "***@dev.****.com", Andpassword: "password");
```

Comment: I have tried this singleton, and code is over https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/793#issuecomment-464352481

Can you please look into this?

Answer (score 0):

I too was having same issue, later discovered that I had not started mongooseIM server.

[Download from here](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html)

Step1: Start server

`mongooseimctl start`

Step2: Check status

`mongooseimctl status`

Step3: Create/Register User

`mongooseimctl register itsyourusername localhost itsapassword`

Step 4: Use these credential in XMPP client framework.

[Official Docs](https://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/Getting-started/)